# subsite owner cannot create subsite, SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a sub-site created under my 2013 SharePoint Site collection. The Sub-site has a unique permission, but the owner of the sub-site is not able to create a sub-site under the sub-site he has full access to. I have added the user to the Site Collection Visitors and Members groups, but he is not still able to create sub-site. The Group he belongs to already has the permission of:
- Manage Permissions
- Create Subsite

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by granting the user limited access to the DeviceChannels.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is because someone removed the 'limited access' to everyone at the site collection level. You need to grant 'everyone' or all authenticated users read access to the Taxonomy Hidden List, `/lists/TaxonomyHiddenList`

Reference:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/156293/2990